# Auto Diff and Merge for Java Strings

Tags: java, string, diff

In my system the user can make changes to JBoss Drools code either through a code editor or a GUI. My problem is if the user makes changes in the code editor and then subsequently in the GUI then the changes from the code editor are lost. Because the GUI tool works by taking a template of the code and plugging in changes made through parameters (FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString).

Does anyone have any suggestions for this problem in general?

One thought was to use [Diff Match Patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) to somehow merge the changes from GUI with those in the code editor. If this is the way could you please share some code (most of what I found online was just for comparing files not for generating the acutal diff from Strings).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First assumption, the change pattern in code editor would always match with the one GUI uses?

e.g., if the file body pattern is something like

```
<some text .........>___ReplaceThisString__<some more text ..............>
```

If it is like that, you could write a method on GUI save, which works something like most of the code repository, like SVN's diff and merge do.

Make a line by line comparison between file saved by code editor (say left) and GUI (say right), you will have 3 conditions,

1. Only left (changes in a line by code editor content)
2. Only in right (changes in a line by GUI)
3. Conflict (a line changed in both code content and GUI)

Ideally, you could merge only left/right without any difficulty, with logic that you take the either change.

For 3rd condition, you must let user decide what to take to maintain correctness of the file functionally, otherwise the file may fail to behave correctly by the next program.

For letting the user decide, you may with to create a compare window showing the user, the difference in two files, and let user simply click on that which one needs to be taken.

Ideally, in all the cases, it is better to show diff and let user confirm that the merge is  not breaking the content integrity of the file.

2 things are important here:

A) The merge functionality should be there for code editor as well as in GUI; whenever someone try to save something from code editor. If it is not possible to have this (say you are using a code editor from a 3rd party, e.g. notepad), you should go for 2-step save-promote solution.

In this case, only saving will not change the actual file, rather the file is written in a different location, as a temporary file.

In step-2, 'promote step' - You should have a tool (build one with above strategy) to compare the temp file and original file. Then the user could visually merge the changes.

Same applies for GUI editor.

B) Whenever you do a compare and merge, the original file must be locked for modification, so that another user do not change the file, while somebody is merging.

Comment: "Make a line by line comparison between file saved by code editor (say left) and GUI (say right)" - Could you please share some code for this?